# How to find the exact value of $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17})$ with WolframAlpha?

Tags: trigonometry, geometric-construction, wolfram-alpha

I tried to find the exact value of $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17})$ with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(2pi%2F17)) but only obtained a decimal approximation. Is there any way to find this exact value with WolframAlpha?

Comment: Are you requiring a rational number? Or rather do you have reason to believe it is a rational number?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth, I know it is not a rational number; however, WolframAlpha can find the exact value of some irrational numbers. Am not sure why it refuses to give me the exact value this time.

Comment: I'm not sure why WolframAlpha can't solve that one, but Mathematica can using `ToRadicals` and you get $\dfrac{1}{4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{2 \left(17-\sqrt{17}\right)}+\sqrt{2 \left(6 \sqrt{17}+\sqrt{2 \left(17-\sqrt{17}\right)}-\sqrt{34 \left(17-\sqrt{17}\right)}+8 \sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{17}+17\right)}+34\right)}+15}}}$

Comment: @JosephEck Thanks! Typing the code for this number is not easy, is it?

Comment: @Zuriel Nope,not all haha. Hope it helps

Comment: @JosephEck, thank you for your effort!

Comment: Just click on "More" under alternate forms.

Comment: @Moo, it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram give the results - see link below.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi17.html

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if WolframAlpha can compute the exact value $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17})$ directly; if not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

First, the value as Gauss wrote it, from Galois Theory by David A. Cox. Cox also shows how Gauss would have derived this, in exrecises in the previous chapter.

[image]

Instead of your number, it is easier to double it, and get a root of
$$  x^8 + x^7 - 7 x^6 - 6 x^5 + 15 x^4  + 10 x^3 - 10 x^2 - 4 x + 1 $$

see page 18 of Reuschle (1875)

[image]
[image]

Note that $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{17} \approx 1.8649444588$

Comment: Thank you! It is not exactly what I was asking but it is helpful to know how to compute the exact value by hand.